# No audio in TS session to Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-7, audio, windows-server-2008, terminal-services

I have a server box with Windows Server 2008 R2 and no audio hardware.  I have installed the "Desktop Experience" feature, and if I plug in a USB headset audio works on the console.

However when I use a TS session to the machine from Windows 7 there is no audio and the icon on the notification area shows "no audio output devices installed".

How can I make audio work on TS sessions?

Answer (score 2):

In RDP settings, under Local Resources tab, click "Settings..." button in Remote audio section and check that "Play on this computer" is selected.

Comment: "Play on this computer" is selected.  Also "Experience" is set for LAN with all the checkboxes checked.   Still no audio.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution we used at work for this issue: cheap USB audio dongles from eBay, less than £2.50 apiece. Stick one in the back of the server and it now has an audio device that it can redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the USB headset is the audio adapter, as well as being a headphone/mic.

If you're unplugging the headset from the server before you RDP into it, then there's no audio device to redirect.

If you *are* leaving them plugged in, and it doesn't redirect it then it's not an audio device that terminal server recognizes as compatible with redirection.

If you are determined to have audio available for redirection perhaps look into a more 'permanent' audio adapter for the server.  Basic PCI(e) sound cards can be had for $20-30 pretty easily these days.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The TS client (Windows 7) has an audio card.  It does not matter if the server has a USB headset plugged in or not.

Comment: What matters is if the server has audio or not.  If it doesn't have audio, then it can't 'redirect' it to the client. :)